# How to hide marker on google map when user press escape key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

With Google map 3.44.10 I show marker on google map and I want to hide marker
when user clicked out of marker or press escape

Define glovar var

```
    markerInfoWindow : null,


        // hide marker when user clicked out of marker - it works ok
        this.locationMap.addListener('click', function (event) {
                if (self.markerInfoWindow) {
                    self.markerInfoWindow.close()
                    self.markerInfoWindow = null
                }
        });



        google.maps.event.addListener(self.locationMarker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                self.markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                let content = ‘CONTENT TEXT’

                self.markerInfoWindow.setContent(content); // I set content for marker and show it
                self.markerInfoWindow.open(self.locationMap, self.locationMarker);

                // Try to catch key events but - failed events are not triggered!
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(self.markerInfoWindow, 'keyup keypress', function (e) {
                    console.log('keyup keypress e::')
                    console.log(e)
                    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                    if (code === 27) {
                        if (self.markerInfoWindow) {
                            self.markerInfoWindow.close()
                            self.markerInfoWindow = null
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        })(this.locationMarker));
```

How correctly ?

Thanks!

Comment: you have nested the keypress listener within the marker click listener... I think that it should be moved out of the marker click listener

Comment: Not the first time you are asked to provide a [mcve]...

Comment: @Professor Abronsius, markerInfoWindow is created when user clicks on marker, that is why I set code inside of listener. I do not see how to make it in other way?

Comment: The example below by @JoshG works perfectly. The `markerInfoWindow` is globally available within the scope of the `initialize` function - so that is one way. Another would be along the lines of your current code - it looks as if you have created a map object class type function ( I think we can see only some of it ) and assigned the map, infowindow as properties of that object... so that is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfoWindows can be closed simply by calling the `close()` method on the InfoWindow, as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).

To dismiss an InfoWindow on escape, just listen for the `keyup` event, check if the key was "Escape", and if so, close the InfoWindow. Likewise, to dismiss an InfoWindow on click, listen for the `click` event.

Example (also [link to a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efadg3m9/) if the snippet doesn't load correctly):

```js
function initialize() {

  let myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.71, -74.00),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    });

  const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Blah Blah Blah",
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

  // dismiss infoWindow on map click
  marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  })

  // dismiss infoWindow on escape press
  document.body.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.key == "Escape") {
      infoWindow.close();
    }
  });

  map.addListener("click", () => {
    infoWindow.close();
  })

}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```